# Eclipse 4.5 Java Formatter changed

Tags: java, eclipse

Today I upgraded Eclipse to Version 4.5.
Since then, it formates differently:

Before:

```
@Override
public void close() {
    try {
        engine.closeSession(session);
        status = NOT_CONNECTED;
    } catch (final OpenpagesException e) {
        log.error("Closing connection failed", e);
    }
}
```

Now:

```
@Override
public void close() {
try {
    engine.closeSession(session);
    status = NOT_CONNECTED;
} catch (final OpenpagesException e) {
    log.error("Closing connection failed", e);
}
}
```

This also happens for: switch, for, if and others...
It looks like the first indention level within a method body is broken.
I reviewed formatting settings but haven't seen something that may be responsible for this.

Is this a bug, or is there a setting?

**Update: 01.07.2015**
It only happens, if the tab size is set to 2, If it's set to 4 everything looks fine besides the waste of space...

**Workaround**
At the formatter settings, switch from Tabs only to mixed.
Then add 2 for Indention size and 2 for Tab size.
Switch setting back to Tabs only and apply everything.
Now formatting works like it did with version 4.4 and it uses 2 for a tab, not 4.

Comment: Are these the formatting settings in `Preferences / Java / Code Style` you have reviewed? In 4.4.2 there is "Statements within method/constructor body"

Comment: Yes, that's the correct location and this is activated since many years...

Comment: Nice response!... 10 seconds late... Downvote for that... That's the spirit!

Comment: Thanks for the work-around! This was preventing me from using Mars. You should answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Workaround**

At the formatter settings, switch from Tabs only to mixed.
Then add 2 for Indention size and 2 for Tab size.
Switch setting back to Tabs only and apply everything.
Now formatting works like it did with version 4.4 and it uses 2 for a tab, not 4.